# Prevent posts while typing in a input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input field as filter. At every keyup he calls a function to post the input.val() to display the result in a table, this works fine. but if i'm typing a name "stackoverflow" he will post 13 times. I want that if he's getting no input for 3 sec that he posts.

I thought that there was a function for (not a default function). And I do not want to auto-complete.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="filter" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#filter").keyup(function(){
        console.log('POST');
    });
 });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fG65Y/)

I don't wants a delay, because that will only "delays" it.

Comment: You'll notice that if you include your code in your post you'll get help much sooner.

Comment: "I don't have to do it"... yes you do, because we don't want to have to follow a link to understand the problem. Also, if the jsfiddle link is down for whatever reason, your question will be incomplete (I admit though that this is a relatively small example and your question might make sense even without it). The better your question, the better answers you get. That implies including code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [jQuery throttle / debounce plugin](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/)

It does exactly what you want

```
$('input').keyup($.debounce(3000, function() { /* Post comes here */ }));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the native Javascript functions clearTimeout and setTimeout to accomplish this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var filterTimeout = null;
    $("#filter").keyup(function(){
        if (filterTimeout != null)
            window.clearTimeout(filterTimeout);
        filterTimeout = window.setTimeout(function() { console.log('POST'); }, 3000);
    });
 });
```